# diferencia entre if(condicion): else: endif y if(condicion){}else{} en php

Tags: php, condiciones

Tengo una duda acerca de php, sopy bastante nuevo en programación web y aun me lio un poco con php.

mi duda es, en un archivo php con la siguiente estructura

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>testero</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
    if(false):
?>
<p>hola</p>
<?php
    else:
?>
<p>adios</p>
<?php
    endif;
?>
</body>
</html>
```

el html que se muestra se corresponde con el codigo php que le rodea, es decir que se muestra solo adios, pero sin embargo en el siguiente ejemplo

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>testero</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
    if(false){
?>
<p>hola</p>
<?php
    }else{
?>
<p>adios</p>
<?php
    }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

se muestran ambas opciones, esto por que sucede? alguien me lo podria explicar porque he estado mirando por stackoverflow ( no he encontrado ninguna pregunta referente a este tema) y por la documentacion oficial de php y no encuentro nada al respecto...

Muchisimas gracias a todos y perdonad si es una pregunta repetida aun ando un poco perdido.

Comment: Bienvenido.. solo como referencia para saber como funciona el sitio, mira [tour]

Comment: Ah y por favor usa el boton [edit] y aclara que fue lo que miraste que no sirvio, para no explicarte lo mismo que ya leiste.

Comment: Hice la prueba con tu código y en ambos casos me muestra sólo "adios"

Comment: No hay diferencia alguna, son prácticamente lo mismo

Comment: solo es estética por así decirlo para cuando se usa html en un archivo php

Comment: No existe diferencia. Si haces el condicional sin llaves {}, solo puedes poner una instrucción. En caso de querer mas de una instrucción en el condicional, es obligatorio el uso de llaves

Answer (score 1):

No hay diferencia en **PHP**, se conocen como [sintaxis alternativas](http://php.net/manual/es/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) , se utilizan normalmente cuando mezclas codigo PHP con HTML, a modo personal prefiero trabajar con `if(false){}else{}` por convencion de codigo